# Is there a function similar to help() in Python in C++

Tags: c++, function

Hey guys I was wondering if there is a function similar to help() in C++. I actually wanted to check the operations defined for a class quickly and as I has used the function help() in Python I thought there must be something similar.

Comment: depending on the IDE you use, or the extensions loaded into it, there is a fair amount of context-sensitive help to be had. 
Do you mind saying which development environment (if any) you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not built-in no; Although technically a compiler could provide such functionality I'm not aware of any that do in a convenient fashion (clang provides a library that you can use to get a C++ AST which you could use to implement a tool like that). The actual language standard doesn't mandate any particular assistance tooling or anything of the sort that an implementation has to provide.

If you want to know about the standard types and functions it's easiest to just look them up in a reference like https://en.cppreference.com/w/. If you want to explore other projects there are often project specific ways to do this (most well run projects will have some amount of internal documentation, for example in the form of Doxygen) and there are various tools that provide functionality useful for such a purpose (like "Go To Declaration" which is something most IDEs and some text editors with some fiddling support).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. C++ is a compiled, not an interpreted language. The language itself doesn't have the `help()` function. Nor does the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: I agree, and you seem to be 3 seconds faster than me, +1!

Comment: This has nothing technically to do with that distinction. Although it does from the perspective of usefulness - such functions are much less useful outside the context of interactive REPL, which languages like C++ tend not to have.

Comment: A more precise answer is thus "C++ does not define an interactive mode, and it's not common to use it in such environment"

Comment: I find the reasoning questionable. Compiled/Interpreted isn't a hard distinction (there are plenty of languages that can be used in both modes) and being a compiled doesn't preclude the existence of interactive tooling (which does in fact exist for C++, just not in any standardised way).

Comment: I don't get why the fact that C++ is compiled matters. A compiler could provide an assistance feature. Plus, [C++ might as well be interpreted](https://root.cern.ch/cling).

Comment: @YSC It matters because there’s no REPL where to execute that function. Yes, C++ REPLs exists but (a) nobody™ uses them and (b) the fact that C++ is compiled is a major reason for the lack of documentation being distributed with libraries in a common format.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OP asked about a _function_ because they come from the Python world, but a compiler flag would do the trick.

Comment: @YSC Leaving reason (b).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is **not**.

Read the documentation online, in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/), or [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com) for example.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function similar to help() in Python in C++

C++ has something **much** better.

C++ compilers automatically generate warning and error reports. 
These are part of the compiler, and require **no interactive prompting**.  You don't even need to ask! (no pinky-strain caused by pressing the help key over and over and over again)

These compilers also support options to increase (or reduce!) the level and detail of the reports.

---

FYI - my typical make file generated compile command is similar to:

g++ -m64  -O3 -ggdb -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wnon-virtual-dtor -pedantic -Werror=vla -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wconversion  -Wpointer-arith -Wunused -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -O0   dumy701.cc  -o dumy701

In the above, from g++ to "dumy701.cc" are a *plethora* of examples of options.  (i.e. for my purpose here, plethora is something more than 17)

In addition, because I sometimes get an error or warning I find difficult to understand (no, not stupidity, just unfamiliarity)(i think), I sometime prefix "g++" with "clan" .. a completely different but compatible compiler, that often produces much more easily understood warning and error messages.

---

Already mentioned in other responses are reference sites. I like en.cppreference.com, which has syntax and often example code.

And the language even allows you add cout or cerr *intermediate* results!

And most tool suites come with a debugger to help figure out what you *thought* was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

May you haven't a keyword like help() in C++, but you have static properties, you can use them to inform the user of the class, about the class description or the description of a method, for example:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
       static string help = "Help text for the class";
       MyClass() {
        ....    
       }
       static string help_method = "Some help for the method";
       void method() {
        ...
       }
};

int main() {
   std::cout << MyClass::help;
   std::cout << MyClass::help_method;
   return 0;
}
```

Maybe isn't neat like Python help(), but it works if you know that you're using these static properties inside your class definition.